# Sitecore: Render content tree child items as list view

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to change the way items in the content tree are rendered in Sitecore?

In Umbraco, there's the option to render all child items of a parent node as either child nodes or in a list view outside of the tree. Next to the tab(s) belonging to the parent node, a node "*child items*" is added. In this node, all child items are rendered in a listview, supporting popular features like paging, sorting and search.

Is this possible in Sitecore?
Upon searching for an answer to this question, the most common reply is to use a *bucket*. However, when using a bucket, a message appears instead of the child nodes: "*There are hidden items in this container*". In a new tab next to the standard *Content* tab, the end user can search for a child item, but it doesn't seem to be possible to show a listview/grid.

So the question remains:

Can we render content tree subitems in a list/grid, in a new tab next to the *Content* tab, using features like paging and sorting.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a default query for your bucket. After that, when a user clicks on the bucket item, he will see search results right away in the form of a list.

Here's documentation on how to do this:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/create_a_default_and_a_persistent_search_query

In short, you just specify your query in the field `Default bucket query` of the bucket item.

I am not aware of any other way of achieving what you want. Sitecore content editor just doesn't have this feature from Umbraco.

Comment: Thanks!
I tried this, it works fine, especially enhanced by the Saved Search option.

However, you always have to trigger a new search, the results tab is not available by default, which can make it a bit confusing for the end user.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the [Subitem Express module](http://www.onenorth.com/blog/post/sitecore-express-subitem-module).

It does not offer features such as a sorting, paging or searching, but it will display and allow editing of children from a single content editing pane, as well as allowing adding new and deleting children. The child items can also be hidden so that they are not visible in the tree by default, but you can enable "hidden items" to still edit the children like regular items.

Really depends on your requirements, but I've used the module for data heavy items where it was easier to enter through the Content Editor than all the fluff around the Experience Editor to speed data entry.

Comment: Cool, this looks like a module that would be useful sometimes! A small caveat here is that subitems will still be visible in the content tree (no way around that).